# Why foo and bar both are parallel?

Tags: javascript

According `You-Dont-Know-JS` **Noninteracting**

```
var res = {};

function foo(results) {
    res.foo = results;
}

function bar(results) {
    res.bar = results;
}

// ajax(..) is some arbitrary Ajax function given by a library
ajax( "http://some.url.1", foo );
ajax( "http://some.url.2", bar );
```

`foo()` and `bar()` are two `concurrent` "processes," and it's nondeterminate which order they will be fired in. But we've constructed the program so it doesn't matter what order they fire in, because they act independently and as such don't need to interact.

I can't understand **`concurrent`** means .

I know JavaScript is single thread. Why `foo` and `bar` are two `concurrent` "processes

Comment: You're confusing *concurrency* with *asynchronism*

Comment: javascript is a good example why single threading is not always a bad thing.

Comment: Aha? Whether Not exactly single-threaded depend on hosting environment ? In fact, JavaScript is a single thread. @ÁlvaroGonzález

Comment: You are right, JS engine is single-threaded and so no two threads run in parallel. But when there is wait state like in ajax call, the switch happens to the next statement. In this case, the second ajax. This is called async behavior. In sync behavior, the second ajax would have been called only when the first ajax call ends. So, because of this async behavior, the two ajax methods are in a way running in parallel. Due to event handling, whichever ajax call returns first, that is picked from the queue.

Answer (score 2):

I think they are "concurrent" (which is a confusion imo) because of ajax() function making them asynchronous, they act like a callback function into a promise, so it will depend on how fast they reach the address in argument and return a value.

Edit: A little drawing just in case it can help :-)
The 2 instructions are fired simultaneously, but as they are asynchronous, the instructions below the 2 ajax calls is executed without waiting a return value

[image]

Here, the first request took 300ms to return the response object of a 'status 200' (grossly foo = 200) while in the second request, twice the time was needed to return 404 and assign it to bar variable.

If you wanted to wait the first ajax call to return something before engaging the second one, you need to check Promises in js, where you do things like `ajax(1, foo).then(ajax(2, bar))` (grossly again)

Comment: Is all ajax funtion "concurrent" ?

For example I have 100 requests of ajax in one page.

Are all of them concurrent?

Comment: No, not concurrent but _asynchronous_.  **A**synchronous **J**avaScript **A**nd **X**ML

Comment: @mqliutie as frikinside said, ajax calls are asynchronous, it means that when it executes the following instructions are executed independently of the results that will be raised by the function later. 

From what I saw, concurrent operations are similar to thread, it implies that what is processed for a function Y is independent from what is processed for a function X /

[URL] Check this:  https://bytearcher.com/articles/parallel-vs-concurrent/

Answer (score 0):

Multi-threading and concurrency are related, but not identical. Rather, multi-threading is one of the ways we can introduce concurrency to a program. But certainly not the *only* way.

In your case, the concurrency that's introduced doesn't come from multi-threading, but rather from the asynchronous `ajax` call (that's what *ajax* means - it's an abbreviation of "Asynchronous Javascript and XML", as opposed to the synchronous methods for doing background requests that were used before ajax). Javascript still executes on a single-thread, but that single thread can alternately be used to process multiple different requests. It only needs to execute when there is code to execute - and the `ajax` call has already returned, just like its caller. The message loop paradigm which has been the staple of GUI programming since about the Apple Macintosh is one way of doing this.

Let's pretend you're trying to write a coöperatively multi-tasked operating system in Javascript. For simplicity, we're going to assume all I/O requires periodic polling (which is *not* how real computers work - they use DMA and interrupts to complete requests on a much lower level than threads). Let's say we have two applications; one is waiting for user input from the keyboard, and another is waiting for a timer:

```
function appQuery() {
  while (true) {
    var input = readUserInput();

    console.log("User input: " + input);
  }
}

function appTimer() {
  while (true) {
    wait(10);

    console.log("Timer tick!");
  }
}
```

How can we allow these two applications to run "at the same time"? Most of the time, neither application requires any CPU at all, so it could just be "waiting" in the background, until their I/O request is satisfied (by a keyboard press or a timer tick, respectively). How can we implement the `readUserInput` and `wait` to "block" the application, without "blocking" the whole system? It turns out that there's quite a few approaches.

The simplest way in Javascript is by using continuations. That is, instead of having simple synchronous (or synchronous-looking) code, we explicitly schedule each asynchronous task with "what happens after". You've probably used this already - it's how both `setTimeout` and `ajax` work. The `setTimeout` method terminates immediately, but the function you pass as an argument is only executed after the timeout passes.

For our case, the code might look something like this:

```
function appQuery() {
  var action = {};
  action = function(input) {
    output.innerText += "User input: " + input + "\r\n";

    actOnUserInput(action);
  }

  actOnUserInput(action);
}

function appTimer() {
  var action = {};
  action = function() {
    output.innerText += "Timer tick!\r\n";

    actOnTimer(10, action);
  }

  actOnTimer(10, action);
}
```

Now both `appQuery` and `appTimer` return immediately, instead of waiting for input or timer. And if you want a workflow with multiple waits, you'd just use multiple continuations in a "sequence". But how do we make sure that they execute their action at the right moment? A simple approach is to use a main loop that keeps track of the multiple tasks and switches between them as soon as their wait condition is completed:

```
var tasks = [];

function mainLoopBody() {
  var taskCount = tasks.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < taskCount; i++) {
    var task = tasks[i];

    if (task.condition()) { // Is the request ready?
      tasks.splice(i, 1);   // 
      task.action();
      i--;
      taskCount--;
    }
  }
}
```

The `actOnXXX` functions are simple enough - they just append a task to the task queue:

```
function actOnUserInput(action) {
  tasks.push({ 
    condition: function() { return currentInput !== noInput; }, 
    action: function () { action(readUserInput()); } 
  });
}

function actOnTimer(timeInSeconds, action) {
    var startTime = Date.now();

  tasks.push({ 
    condition: function() { return startTime + (timeInSeconds * 1000) <= Date.now(); }, 
    action: function () { action(); } 
  });
}
```

Now, if we were actually running this in a console application, all we'd have to do is `while (true) mainLoopBody();`. But since we're in a GUI application with its own message loop, we need to use a different approach:

```
appQuery(); // Schedule query app
appTimer(); // Schedule timer app

setInterval(mainLoopBody, 100); // Run the OS!
```

The `setInterval` basically tells the browser's message loop to give *our* message loop a chance once in a while; in a real computer, this would roughly correspond to a CPU timer interrupt (that's how preëmptive multi-tasking works as well).

To tie everything up, we still need to give ourselves a page to live  in:

```
<input id="userInput" />
<button onclick="setInput();">OK</button>

<div id="output" />
```

And finally, our pretend-input-buffer (in a typical single-threaded, GUI-less system like MS-DOS, this would *roughly* correspond to an input interrupt handler):

```
var noInput = {};
window.currentInput = noInput;

window.setInput = function() {
  if (currentInput !== noInput) return; // We only allow one input in the buffer

  currentInput = userInput.value;
  userInput.value = '';
}

function readUserInput() {
  var input = currentInput;
  currentInput = noInput;
  return input;
}
```

And there you have it - two "useful" applications running concurrently on a single-thread, and you can run as many of them as you want concurrently (until you run out of CPU or memory, of course). There's never a point where both applications are using the CPU at the same time, but most applications don't need all that much CPU - you're usually waiting for some kind of I/O.

If you're interested, you can play around with the full example at https://jsfiddle.net/sjy0mgy7/1/ :)